pointing a domain birdcope.com of DomainAcccount to a sub Folder on HostingAccount in namescheap
I have two namescheap accounts - hostingAccount and domainAccount.
My domain birdcope.com is registered on DomainAccount.
I want to point this domain to hostingAccount's sub folder.
there is already a wordpress site in my hosting account document root /home/petpbyrt/public_html. I want to create another site whose content should show when I write birdcope.com in the browser url.
PS: my hosting account does not support add on domains it only supports sub domains.

You can't point a domain name to a folder, only an IP address.   You then configure the web server to pick up domain name (which is provided with the HTTP(s) request) and associate it with the appropriate folder.  It is probable you will not be able to make HTTPS work if you can't add the domain to the web server.  Really though, you should be reaching out to Namecheap.
